# Android: Custom ListView Drawing

Tags: android, listview, layout, drawing

Consider me an Android noob;
I'm trying to create a custom ListView, that should look something like this ('this' is a custom ListView implemented in BlackBerry, but I want to create the same look and feel on Android):[image: Custom ListView with rounded corners, implemented on BlackBerry]

I've currently come up with the following Android code and XML, but it doesn't change the looks of the standard ListView:

The code:

```
public class RoundedListView extends ListView
{
    public RoundedListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RoundedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RoundedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {       
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

        canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10, paint);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The XML (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.gravityzoo.android.containers.RoundedListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/listView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </com.gravityzoo.android.containers.RoundedListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to make this simple drawing function working?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Android is quite different from Blackberry.

In Android you would want to set backgrounds and margins on the items of the `ListView` to achieve the above effects. There is usually no need to combine custom drawing with "normal" members of the view hierarchy like `ListView`, `TextView`, etc.

Often in Blackberry development you would subclass a framework field just to provide it with a custom width and height. In Android you can do this with simple "composition"; in other words, instantiating a component and then setting attributes on it without subclassing.

Another important point is that `ListView` tends to be for homogeneous data, where all of the rows follow the same general format or a small group of formats. **If you only have four items, and each of the items have different characteristics, then I suggest you use a plain old `LinearLayout`** which will allow you to position your views vertically. This will save you quite a bit of work shoe-horning your four views into an adapter and give you maximum control over how each item is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another couple of places you can start looking around for this simple layout:

http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

All this seems to be is a couple of edittexts and buttons within a listview.